# Anyone familiar with a press87.php file – is this a hack?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla3.0

I just noticed a strange file on the Joomla install on my server named "press87.php" that isn't associated with anything in particular. It seems to be encrypted and, doing a search on the interweb, it seems to show up in a number of directories – including WP installs – but in seemingly random places. Is this a hack? Does anyone know anything about this?

The original code contained in the file can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/J8fe5RP1

Cheers!

Comment: It’s indeed not unlikely that this is a backdoor or something similar. Care to post  the code?

Comment: Uh … no. I will *not* download some zip file with questionable content. If the amount of code is so large, then please post it to some pastebin.

Comment: Sorry, totally understand. Try this -->

[link]http://pastebin.com/J8fe5RP1

Comment: I would suggest you also change all the admin passwords and any ftp passwords. Basically, assume all your 'control' passwords are compromised.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, ryan. i will definitely change EVERYTHING!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is definitely malicious and appears to be a backdoor with a mail server.

The code is obfuscated through base64 and some character rotation, but can be pretty easily be uncovered by replacing the `eval` in the last line with `print`.

The un-obfuscated PHP code can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/zyH8axSK

So, what does that mean? Somebody found a way to place PHP files on your webserver and intends to abuse for spamming.

I would guess that there’s a security issue with either your Joomla installation itself or some plugin. To get clean again, you should:

- Make a backup of your database and (legitimate) user uploaded files,
- Remove *all* files of your Joomla install (because even “real” Joomla files might be infected by now).
- Re-install Joomla from a fresh download. Same with all plugins.
- Restore the Joomla database backup.
- Change *all* user passwords and remove suspicious accounts.
- Re-install the user uploaded files, but check every single one for a possible infection.

Do *not* just remove the backdoor files and think you’re done, because you’ll be infected tomorrow again if you don’t fix the security issue that allowed the malicious file upload.

Comment: thanks for looking into this and providing the suggestions, lxg! i will definitely start fresh.